# Как вызвать action из другого контроллера, который в модуле

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте, как вызвать метод из другого контроллера в модуле? Я сейчас нахожусь в представлении SiteControlle/index, хочу сюда вызвать LoginAction, который находится в контроллере AccountController в модуле user. Пробовал так:

```
list($controller) = Yii::app()->createController('account');
echo $controller->Login();
```

так:

```
Yii::app()->getModule('user');
list($controller) = Yii::app()->createController('account');
echo $controller->Login();
```

и так:

```
list($controller) = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->createController('account');
echo $controller->Login();
```

подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function actions ()
{
    $actions = array(
            'login' => 'actions.PATH.LoginAction',
    )
}
```

Это добавляете в оба контроллера.
После чего в папку actions запихиваете новый экшн-класс:

```
class LoginAction extends CAction
{
    public function run($id=0)
    {
            //код экшена
    }
}
```

Тогда у вас два контроллера будут иметь общий экшн

UPD:
PATH - это подпапки в вапке actions, если таковые есть.
Например: actions.users.auth.LoginAction

Comment: теперь у меня контроллер accaunt состоит только из этой функции:

public function actions()
    {
        return array(           
            'login'            => array(
                'class' => 'application.modules.user.controllers.account.LoginAction',
            ),
            'logout'           => array(
                'class' => 'application.modules.user.controllers.account.LogOutAction',
            ),
        );
    } 

И в siteController добавил, там еще есть отдельная функция actionIndex(){} 

в представлении пробовал и $this->Login, еще по всякому, а как еще можно вызвать?

Comment: В представлении контроллер вызывать не нужно. 
представление вообще не должно содержать логики, за исключением логики отображения.  
Если требуется ввод логина для незарегистрированных, делайте это в контроллере.
Если требуется вездесущее окошечко авторизации - в виджете.

Если уж на то пошло, то не $this->Login, а $this->actionLogin(); Но это уже мелочи. Не делайте так.